# Colleagues birthday manager

Tags: open-source, reminders, sms

I want a program to manage my colleagues birthdays, just for fun. Everybody enters their information. When a birthday comes up, it should send an SMS to the other members.

Is there any open source package (desktop, webapp) available to do this?